# How to manage html elements in their container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a div which represents a bread crumb.

Link 1 / Link2 / Link 3

and so on. The div occupies the browser's width. Whenever I resize the browser if the available width is not enough then I want to show the bread crumb like one of the following

1)
Link 1 / ... / Link 3

2)
... / Link 3

Clicking on the ... will show entire bread crumb but scrollbars will appear

As far I know I have to use window resize handler events but confused how to start because there are many components on which I want to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do it :

- on window resize, check if the div width is < to the total of its
  children width (link1 width + link2 width, and so on) and put it as a function.
- if it's true, replace text of the middle link with "..." and store the original text in a data-attribute (for example), and recall the first function (so whenever the width of the children elements > the div element, it will replace anchor text by "..."
- then, on div click, replace all "..." by their original text stored in a data-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [this plugin](http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html), which automatically collapses and expands your breadcrumb.

You could pass it different values of `endElementsToLeaveOpen`depending on how wide your window is.